# CSS Header Position Fixed Removes Spacing

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'll start by saying, I'm not great with CSS, so this may be simple. I have a table with a header which I'd like to be fixed when scrolling. When I add position:fixed to the CSS, it is fixed when scrolling, but loses it's spacing format.

Before 'position:fixed' :
[image]

This is after 'position:fixed':
[image]

```css
.consumer-service-table-header-style {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<thead class="consumer-service-table-header-style">
   <tr>
      <td align="left">            
           <label style="font-weight: bold;">Pull Date</label>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
           <label style="font-weight: bold;">Rate</label>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
           <label style="font-weight: bold;">Service SubCat</label>
      </td>

      <td align="left">
         <label style="font-weight: bold;">ClientServiceIdMin</label>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
         <label style="font-weight: bold;">ClientServiceIdMax</label>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
         <label style="font-weight: bold;">Provider Name</label></td>
      <td align="left">
         <label style="font-weight: bold;">RatePullId</label>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
         <label style="font-weight: bold;">DDS #</label>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: Change position: fixed; to position: fixed *important;

Comment: I did, same outcome :-/

Comment: Is you table set to be at 100% width? It won't work without it.

Comment: <table width="100%" id="rate-pull-table" class="consumer-service-table-style" cellspacing="0px">

Comment: I think I know what is happening. I am creating the rows on the server side and passing them to the client side. I don't think the header is dynamically resizing based on the length of the cell being passed back...

Comment: it works for me. I replicated your code in a plain html file.

Answer (score 0):

adding `display: table;` to your class should keep it all nicely spaced!

Comment: Better, but still off. It's getting close!

Comment: you could also try adding `display: table-cell` to your `td`s

Comment: If I do this, and don't add a 'width' property to the header css, it scrunches it all, if I add a "width: 100%" to the header css, the header goes outside of my div.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're having a `div` around your table with a specified width. When you change `position: fixed;` to `position fixed *important;` **and** add `display:table;` to the class `.consumer-service-table-header-style`, you should get the desired result.